# JavaScript Rock Paper Scissors Game, alert function

Tags: javascript, alert

I am attempting to make my first Rock paper scissors game. I am having trouble with the alert() function. Whenever I open the document I get the prompt 'Make your decision!' but when I answer the prompt there is not return saying whether the AI or the Humans won the round.

```
const Humanity = 0;
const AI = 0;

//Create function to generate random computer choice 

function getComputerChoice() { 

    const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    const randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    const decision = choices[randomChoice];
    return decision;

 } getComputerChoice();

 //play a round of game


 function round() {

    let computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    let playerDecision = prompt('Make your decision!', ''.toLowerCase());


    if (playerDecision === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'scissors') {
        Humanity += 1;
        alert('Humanity Wins');
    } else if (playerDecision === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'paper') {
        Humanity +=1;
        alert('Humanity Wins');
    } else if (playerDecision === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'rock') {
        Humanity += 1;
        alert('Humanity Wins');
    } else if (playerDecision === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'paper') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI Wins');
    } else if (playerDecision === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'rock') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI Wins');
    } else if (playerDecision === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'scissors') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI Wins');
    } 

 } round();
```

I expect the alert to pop up once I have entered the prompted question.

Comment: You need `let Humanity = 0; let AI = 0;`. They cannot be const if you want to modify them. Also, you need to handle the case of a draw.

Comment: Did you check console for error message?

Comment: I did check the console and I am not getting any error or warning messages

Comment: @Pete1230z Just don't use `const` and you won't have an issue... Also, your code definitely does produce an error, namely: "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable"

Answer (score 1):

When running your code I am getting an error.

> "Assignment to constant variable."

This is your problem. I presume you're new to JS. Instead of declaring variables const, declare them as "var" or "let"

- **let**: Available in the scope you declare them
- **var**: Available inside the full function (or js file if you declare them outside of a function)
- **const**: Something you won't change

In that case, it would be good if you declare your array "choices" as const at the top of your Js, even outside of the functions.

And a tip for your game, that is one verification missing, the draw! Keep going!